# visual studio code syntax error with unknown space

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, space

When I write my python code, suddenly invalid syntax (, line 207) appears in PROBLEMS tab and I cannot't run my code.

[image]

Red wave is error. So I started to remove this space 
[image]

[image]

[image]

But this error space leave endlessly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the future, please post plain text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got nothing with space. Line 207 on 1st image is invalid. You got closing square bracket, but opening one is nowhere around.